# Embedded objects in MS Office documents using Python?

Tags: python, windows, com, ms-office, ole

How could I create embedded objects in an MS office document using Python?

I don't need anything fancy, just what one used to do in the first version of OLE:  doing a copy-paste from my application into e.g. MS Word should give me an object embedded in the Word document, which I can then  double-click to open a copy of my application and edit the object.

Can this be done from a Python/PyQt application (perhaps using pythoncom?) Are there any simple examples of this that can get me started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OLE compound documents enable users working within a single application to manipulate data written in various formats and derived from multiple sources. A compound document object is essentially a COM object that can be embedded in, or linked to, an existing document. As a COM object, a compound document object exposes the [`IUnknown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680509(VS.85).aspx) interface, through which clients can obtain pointers to its other interfaces, including several, such as [`IOleObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd542709(VS.85).aspx), [`IOleLink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682297(VS.85).aspx), and [`IViewObject2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms691318(VS.85).aspx), that provide special features unique to compound document objects.

You'll use [pywin32 extensions](http://python.net/crew/skippy/win32/Downloads.html). This [COM tutorial](http://www.boddie.org.uk/python/COM.html) can get you started (I hope). Most info you need will come from [microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680573(VS.85).aspx) itself. There's a [book on the subject](http://oreilly.com/catalog/pythonwin32/chapter/ch12.html).

Comment: Thanks, this will get me started. Since I'm completely new to COM, it would really help to have a code example, but I haven't found one anywhere... I'll have to give it a try.